# Why does adding quotation changes the expression's value in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, shell, powershell-7.0

I have just started to learn Powershell, and there is one thing I just can't wrap my head around. See below:

```
> Write-output $(Get-Date -DisplayHint Date)  
    //Expect: Tuesday, November 3, 2020
    //Got: Tuesday, November 3, 2020

> Write-output "$(Get-Date -DisplayHint Date)" 
    //Expect: Tuesday, November 3, 2020
    //Got: 11/03/2020 20:42:27
```

For the second line with quotation interpolation, can someone explain why it is showing a different format?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default format for the `ToString()` method in the current culture. This output is the result of "turning it into a string". The following examples all result in similar output as they are converting to string.

**Write-Host (converts the output to a string)**

```
Write-Host (Get-Date -DisplayHint Date)

11/3/2020 11:46:00 PM
```

**ToString()**

```
(Get-Date -DisplayHint Date).ToString()

11/3/2020 11:48:55 PM
```

**-as operator**

```
(Get-Date -DisplayHint Date) -as [string]

11/03/2020 23:49:37
```

**String interpolation**

```
"{0}" -f (Get-Date -DisplayHint Date)

11/3/2020 11:51:27 PM
```

And of course you already discovered converting to string by enclosing in quotes.

If you want to control how it's formatted, here are a few ways.

```
(Get-Date).ToLongDateString()

Tuesday, November 3, 2020

(Get-Date).ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy")

Tuesday, November 3, 2020

Get-Date -f "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy"

Tuesday, November 3, 2020
```

Answer (score -1):

Date can be showed in a customised way when it is converted into string.
In the above code you have enclosed in double quotes, which powershell treats it as a string.
(Get-Date -DisplayHint Date).toString() may also give you same result.